# Unexpected Application Error! Github pages

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

Trying to upload my react.js project to github pages, but I have such error while trying to open gh page: "Unexpected Application Error! 404 not found"
My code:

```
{
  "name": "typing-training-app",
  "homepage": "https://*****.github.io/*******",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

Tried to delete "homepage" from code, still doesn't work

Comment: is your github pages site set to your username or to the repo you wish to upload?

https://docs.github.com/en/pages/quickstart

Comment: Website's link is https://{username}.github.io/{repo name}/

Comment: could you share a link to the repo so could help troubleshoot?

Comment: Same issue I am also facing!

Comment: Same issue here, any clue ?